# how to write several statements in the same line in J

Tags: j

I am a newbie and try to learn J. There is one question I have had for quite some time.

What is the statement separator in `J`? Can I write several statements in the same line in J?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [MPelletier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733775/349708) notes, there is no statement operator but you can use the "assignment trick": assign the result of a statement to a variable when you use it, the first time (from right to left) that you use it. Eg:

Instead of this:

```
a =: 15
f =: (+/) % # i.a
g =: (-/) % # i.a
h =: ((-:g) * (+:f)) ^ ((-:f) * (+:g))
```

you can write this:

```
h =: ((-:g) * (+:f)) ^ ((-: f =. (+/) % #i.a) * (+: g =. (-/) % # i.a=.15))
```

Or, instead of:

```
mean =: (+/) % #
f =: mean i.15
```

this:

```
f =: (mean =: (+/) % #) i.15
```

Comment: :/ that's just chaining definitions, and clever, careful use of parentheses. You can do the same in C, but C allows you to separate completely independent statements too. No sour grapes though.

Comment: @MPelletier you are absolutely right; I only meant this reply as a comment but got too long for a comment. But also, you can't nest functions in _standard_ C.

Comment: @MPelletier, @user1951460: [@bob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17793803/349708) has the right answer. `a =. 3 *2 [ z=. 8 [ (b=: 3 :'+:y') [ c=. *:9`.

Answer (score 4):

Although the statement separator in J is the linefeed, you can separate assignment statements on a single line by using the Left verb (dyadic [) which always returns its left argument. Since J parses right to left, the Left verb effectively breaks up statements as the right argument is discarded (although side effects such as assignment still occur).

```
   2 + 3 [ t=. 3 + 4
5
  t
7
```

So in this case t is assigned 7 and then 3 [ t is evaluated returning 3 which is added to 2. In contrast if you use Right (dyadic ]) you may be swimming upstream with different results.

```
   2 + 3 ] t=. 6 + 4
12
   t
10
```

Here t is assigned 10 and the result of 3 ] t is t with a value of 10 which is then added to 2.

Hope this helps, bob

Answer (score 3):

There is no statement separator. Or rather, the statement separator is a line feed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [Do `".`](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/quotedot), you can create an anonymous verb with [Explicit Verb `3 :`](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/coa) and invoke it. This way you don't need to worry about leaked temporary variables.

For multiple statements, you have some way:

1. Reverse statements and join with `[` (ex. `'bar =. foo + 54 [ foo =. 42'` )
2. Concat with line feeds (ex. `'foo =. 42' , LF , 'bar =. foo + 54'`)
3. Shape code as a table (ex. `'foo =. 42' ,: 'bar =. foo + 54'`).

Borrowing [Eelvex's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734660/):

```
   (3 : 'h =. ((-:g) * (+:f)) ^ ((-:f) * (+:g)) [ g =. (-/) % # i.a [ f =. (+/) % # i.a [ a =. 15') ''
0.976216
   (3 : ('a =. 15' ,LF, 'f =. (+/) % # i.a' ,LF, 'g =. (-/) % # i.a' ,LF, 'h =. ((-:g) * (+:f)) ^ ((-:f) * (+:g))')) ''
0.976216
   (3 : ('a =. 15' , 'f =. (+/) % # i.a' , 'g =. (-/) % # i.a' ,: 'h =. ((-:g) * (+:f)) ^ ((-:f) * (+:g))')) ''
0.976216
```

Somehow `3 : <...>` gets evaluated before usual right-to-left execution, so you need  parentheses for the right hand of `:`. Using this behavior, you can omit parentheses around `3 : <...>`:

```
   3 : '6 * 9' ''
54
```